# How to remap keys with Dvorak layout enabled?

Tags: keyboard-layout, dvorak

I'd like to remap a key or two (mostly my tab key), but I'd also like to use the Dvorak layout. I've found that an .Xmodmap file makes using the Dvorak layout impossible to use. My question is are there any ways to remap the key without causing me this interference problem?

Comment: Tumbleweed badge, huh? That's harsh...